# Problems with getPosition() in SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm new to c++ so I'm a bit confused on this one. I'm trying to have the player spawn, then when the user presses "C", the player switches with a car. What's happening currently is the player is initially spawning in the correct location, then the car is spawning where the player initially spawned, not where it currently is. However, since I'm using the function `getPosition()`, I would assume it would spawn in the current position of the player.

Player.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <string>
class player {

public:
    sf::Texture normalTexture;
    sf::Sprite normalSprite;
    sf::Texture carTexture;
    sf::Sprite carSprite;
    sf::Texture springTexture;
    sf::Sprite springSprite;
    sf::Texture rocketTexture;
    sf::Sprite rocketSprite;
    sf::IntRect normalRect[1];
    sf::IntRect carRect[1];
    sf::IntRect springRect[1];
    sf::IntRect rocketRect[1];


bool rocket=false;
bool car=false;
bool spring=false;
bool normal=false;

player();
player(sf::Vector2f position, std::string normalFileLoc, std::string carFileLoc, std::string springFileLoc, std::string rocketFileLoc);

void update();
};
```

Player.cpp:

```
#include "Player.h"

player::player() : player::player(sf::Vector2f(100, 0), "player.jpg", "car.png", "spring.png", "rocket.png") {
}

player::player(sf::Vector2f position, std::string normalFileLoc, std::string 
carFileLoc, std::string springFileLoc, std::string rocketFileLoc)
{
normalTexture.loadFromFile(normalFileLoc);
normalRect[0] = sf::IntRect(0, 0, 64, 128);
normalSprite.setTexture(normalTexture);
normalSprite.setTextureRect(normalRect[0]);
normalSprite.setOrigin(0,0);
normalSprite.setScale(1, 1);
normalSprite.setPosition(position.x, position.y);

carTexture.loadFromFile(carFileLoc);
carRect[0] = sf::IntRect(0, 0, 64, 64);
carSprite.setTexture(carTexture);
carSprite.setTextureRect(carRect[0]);
carSprite.setOrigin(0, -64);
carSprite.setScale(1, 1);
carSprite.setPosition(normalSprite.getPosition().x, normalSprite.getPosition().y);

}
```

Main.cpp I know it looks gross, I plan on making it look nicer later:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML\Graphics\Rect.hpp>
#include "player.h"
int main()
{
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(750, 750), "SFML Works!");

player thePlayer;

const float gravity = .001;
int groundheight = 500;
sf::Vector2f velocity(sf::Vector2f(0, 0));

thePlayer.normal = true;


while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();

        if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
        {
            if (thePlayer.car && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::C)
            {
                thePlayer.car = false;
                thePlayer.spring = false;
                thePlayer.rocket = false;
                thePlayer.normal = true;
                break;
            }
            if (thePlayer.spring && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::S)
            {
                thePlayer.car = false;
                thePlayer.spring = false;
                thePlayer.rocket = false;
                thePlayer.normal = true;
                break;
            }
            if (thePlayer.rocket && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::R)
            {
                thePlayer.car = false;
                thePlayer.spring = false;
                thePlayer.rocket = false;
                thePlayer.normal = true;
                break;
            }
            if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::C)
            {
                thePlayer.car = true;
                thePlayer.spring = false;
                thePlayer.rocket = false;
                thePlayer.normal = false;
                break;
            }
            if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::R)
            {
                thePlayer.car = false;
                thePlayer.spring = false;
                thePlayer.rocket = true;
                thePlayer.normal = false;
                break;
            }
            if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::S)
            {
                thePlayer.car = false;
                thePlayer.spring = true;
                thePlayer.rocket = false;
                thePlayer.normal = false;
                break;
            }

        }

    }



    if (thePlayer.normal)
    {
        velocity.x = 0;
        thePlayer.normalSprite.move(velocity.x, velocity.y);
        if (thePlayer.normalSprite.getPosition().y < groundheight)
        {
            velocity.y += gravity;
        }
        else
        {
            thePlayer.normalSprite.setPosition(thePlayer.normalSprite.getPosition().x, groundheight);
            velocity.y = 0;
        }

    }

    if (thePlayer.car)
    {
        thePlayer.carSprite.move(velocity.x, velocity.y);
        if (thePlayer.carSprite.getPosition().y < groundheight)
        {
            velocity.y += gravity;
        }
        else
        {
            thePlayer.carSprite.setPosition(thePlayer.carSprite.getPosition().x, groundheight);
            velocity.y = 0;
        }

    }

    window.clear();
    if (thePlayer.normal)
    {
        window.draw(thePlayer.normalSprite);
    }
    if (thePlayer.car)
    {
        window.draw(thePlayer.carSprite);
    }

    window.display();
}
}
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you show us the code where you make the car spawn ?

Comment: Sure, give me one second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before drawing the car you should adjust its position to your player position :

```
if (thePlayer.car)
{
    thePlayer.carSprite.setPosition(thePlayer.normalSprite.getPosition());
    window.draw(thePlayer.carSprite);
}
```

But as ractiv said, you should organize your code differently. I suggest you to learn more about c++ "good pratices" before trying to do this kind of games.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: About "good pratices" of coding, your code is working but you should organize it differently

Answer (score 0):

We miss the `main` function to know exactly what happens when the car spawns but I think that you initialize the car in the Player constructor and does not move it when the player presses 'C'.

You should have something like that :

```
if(event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::C) {
    player.spawnCar();
}
```

and in your `spawnCar()` function :

```
carSprite.setPosition(normalSprite.getPosition());
```

**EDIT**

As I said in my comment, you should use getters and setters to access to your attributes. According to your current main.cpp, you should have this :

```
if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::C)
{
    thePlayer.car = true;
    thePlayer.spring = false;
    thePlayer.rocket = false;
    thePlayer.normal = false;
    carSprite.setPosition(normalSprite.getPosition());
    break;
}
```

Comment: Should the spawnCar() function be in Player.h or Player.cpp?

Comment: It depends how you organize your code. I recommend you to set your attributes private and add getters and setters to your class. What I use to do is to declare the attributes and methods in the header file and implement them is a .cpp file.